# Why is $\Xi \equiv 0$ if $E=C_{0}(X \times Y)$?

Tags: optimal-transportation

I'm reading the proof of Kantorovich duality from Villani's book *Topics in Optimal Transportation*. In page 28, the author said that

> **Exercise 1.11.** Let us try to extend this proof to the non-compact case. Why would we like to replace $C_{b}(X \times Y)$ by $C_{0}(X \times Y) ?$ Show that if we do so in the definition of $\Xi$, then the latter turns out to be trivial: $\Xi \equiv 0$. This shows that the proof as such does not work in a non-compact setting. Still, a variation of it can be used, as we shall see later in Appendix 1.3.

Let $X$ and $Y$ be Polish spaces. Let $E:=C_{0}(X \times Y)$ be the space of all continuous vanishing at infinity functions on $X \times Y$, equipped with its usual supremum norm $\|\cdot\|_{\infty}$. Let
$$
\Xi: u \in E \longmapsto\left\{\begin{array}{l}
\int_{X} \varphi d \mu+\int_{Y} \psi d \nu &\begin{align*}
&\text {if } u = \varphi \oplus \psi \text{ for some } (\varphi, \psi) \in C_b(X) \times C_b(Y)
\end{align*}\\
+\infty &\text {else. }
\end{array}\right.
$$

I could not see how $\Xi \equiv 0$. For example, take some $(\varphi, \psi) \in C_0(X) \times C_0(Y)$. Then define $u$ by $u (x,y) := \varphi(x)+ \psi(y)$. Then $u \in E$. However, $\int_{X} \varphi d \mu+\int_{Y} \psi d \nu$ is possibly nonzero.

> Could you explain why $\Xi \equiv 0$ if $E=C_{0}(X \times Y)$?

Comment: Are you sure that $X$ and $Y$ are Polish only? Maybe they are locally compact too.

Comment: @DieterKadelka I guess to prove $\Xi \equiv 0$, it's sufficient to assume that $X,Y$ are Polish.

Comment: The problem only is: What is "vanishing at infinity", f.i. what if $X = Y = C([0,1])?

Comment: @DieterKadelka in the book $f:X \to \mathbb R$ is vanishing at infinity if $\forall \varepsilon>0, \exists K \subset X$ compact such that $|f(x)| \le \varepsilon$ for all $x \in X \setminus K$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A function $u(x,y) = \varphi(x) + \psi(y)$ with $\varphi\in C_0(X)$ and $\psi\in C_0(Y)$ will not be in $C_0(X,Y)$ if $\varphi$ or $\psi$ is not constant zero: If $x$ "tends to infinity", we have $\varphi(x)\to 0$, but $u(x,y)\to\psi(y)$ which is not zero in general.

Comment: It seems the statement in the exercise holds only when $X,Y$ are **both** non-compact. Could you confirm if my observation is correct? [...]

Comment: [...] Assume $X$ is not compact and $Y$ is compact. Let $(\varphi, \psi) \in C_0(X) \times C_0(Y)$ such that $\psi \equiv 0$. Define $u (x,y) := \varphi(x)+ \psi(y)$. Indeed, $u \in C_0(X \times Y)$. Fix $\varepsilon>0$. There is a compact set $K \subset X$ such that $\sup_{x \notin K} |\varphi(x)| \le \varepsilon$. Clearly, $K \times Y$ is compact. Also,
$$
\sup \{ |u(x,y)| \mid (x,y) \notin K \times Y\} = \sup \{ |\varphi(x)| \mid x \notin K
\} \le \varepsilon.
$$

Comment: If you don't mind, please have a look at another closely related question [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/422491/the-significance-of-continuity-in-the-proof-of-kantorovich-duality).

Comment: Phew, I am not sure if I find the time and energy to chase down that detail…

Comment: Thank you so much for your help :v